# In landscape mode the splash screen theme makes bar under camera white

Tags: android, xml, kotlin, themes, splash-screen

I implemented the splash pack on my android app.

```
implementation 'androidx.core:core-splashscreen:1.0.0'
```

However, color of the bar under camera turned to white after splash screen in landscape orientation. Before splash screen it was black. How to modify it?
[image]

XML codes of splash screen theme

```
<resources>
    <style name="Theme.Zebraman.Starting" parent="Theme.SplashScreen">
        <item name="windowSplashScreenBackground">@color/darkThemeTopBar</item>
        <item name="windowSplashScreenAnimatedIcon">@mipmap/ic_splash_dark_round</item>
        <item name="postSplashScreenTheme">@style/Theme.Zebraman</item>
    </style>
</resources>
```

Answer (score 1):

I hope this will help

```
<style name="SplashTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.NoActionBar">
    <item name="android:windowBackground">@drawable/splashscreen</item>
    <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/colorPrimaryDark</item>
</style>
```